How to calculate times in variable cells
I am trying to create an Excel file that logs diver times. Specifically, I am logging their in/out times, total dive time, and surface intervals. If you're not a diver, the total dive time is the total time under water from the surface, back to the surface. The surface interval is the amount of time elapsed from the time they completed a dive until the take their next dive.
With the above said, calculating total dive time is easy. But the surface interval is where things get complicated:
In the dive log, a single diver can occupy any of the cells. In any given day a diver can dive pretty much at any time (for sake of argument for those who are divers). As such, I need to automatically calculate for a single diver in any given position in the list of divers, what their surface interval was from the previous dive. So you have a good idea of what I am talking about, I have included a photo of the spreadsheet:
Notice how Joe diver definitely wants to get his money's worth of diving! He dives 5 times. Just pretend that all of the other divers are hopping into and out of the water at different times between Joe diver's dives. In this form, Tdt=total dive time and tsi= total surface interval. As you can see, his (Joe diver's) first surface interval was 0. His second and third was 1 hour, fourth was 2 hours and third was 3 hours.
As you can tell, a formula of =c4-d5 in the f4 cell, doesn't work in the current list... At all. I must use the former c cell for Joe diver in conjunction with the current d cell for Joe diver to give me the proper result in the f4 cell. Assume the columns are labeled a-f (because they are).

Now, I COULD make a sheet for every diver, but being that divers are constantly going into and out of the water, this is inefficient as there could be 50 divers, this will be on a tablet, and I must have a running tab for all divers sequentially as they get in the water... Basically, what you see is what I want to use. It would also be a nightmare for printing on paper to print 50 different sheets of paper.
How can I create a good solution to this issue?

"Excel gods" prefer data over text. Please edit your question to include data (as markdown table, using for instance https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Please also include at least one example of expected result with sample data.

If I understand correctly F13 shouldn't be 3:00?

If That's the case, I understand. Please confirm. And how to handle a first value?

@P.b. I kind of figured that the screenshot of my Excel sheet would do as the example of my expected results.

@Balázs correct, I meant to edit that before screen shotting it, but I was multi-tasking. The main point is that the formula I'm seeking must make the calculations automatically and correctly.

This is the formula in F3 and drag down
=LET(last,C3-MAX(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(INDIRECT("A$2:D"&(ROW()-1)),INDIRECT("A$2:A"&(ROW()-1))=A3),4)), IF(IFERROR(last,"")<0,"Error",IFERROR(last,"")))
Search in the previous rows for the max. time out value for the actual diver name and subtract it from the time in value.


Sorry for the late reply. I am a truck driver by trade, and the past few days have been crazy. How would I edit the formula to make the diver names in the B cell, and still work? I have tried myself, but I only get errors in the f cells, or nothing at all.

=IFNA(C4-XLOOKUP(B4,B$3:B3,D$3:D3,,,-1),0)

@PiGuy88 Simply change letter A to B in  all the cell references.  =LET(last,C3-MAX(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(INDIRECT("B$2:D"&(ROW()-1)),INDIRECT("B$2:B"&(ROW()-1))=B3),4)), IF(IFERROR(last,"")<0,"Error",IFERROR(last,"")))

@Black Cat, unfortunately, this formula is resulting in blank cells.

@P.b this formula either results in blank cells, # spanning a cell, or times that read 0:00.

Yes, I missed to change a reference of a column (the value 4 to 3). Try this: =LET(last,C3-MAX(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(INDIRECT("B$2:D"&(ROW()-1)),INDIRECT("B$2:B"&(ROW()-1))=B3),3)), IF(IFERROR(last,"")<0,"Error",IFERROR(last,"")))

@PiGuy88 https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPCgZUMZSZvVjKMeVpL2Q?e=j0BZMz&nav=MTVfe0JENTI1OTlBLUNDRDMtNDAxRS1BMkNCLTI3Njk4M0EzMUNGRn0

@Black cat, OK, so we're pretty close! Now the issue is that the error message displays when the 24 hour period lapses. It also occurs randomly. Link to the spreadshee5 is included below.https://1drv.ms/x/c/2f744b1ec0ff7a43/EUoStYqEiG5Pu6yHe4wfXd0B_Sjhwb8JAk6C4zzjA-9XaQ?e=5SE5r9
